# tabBarController navigationItem.title color

Tags: ios, swift

I am setting the title as follows, but I want to change the color of the text as well, but there is no `textattributes`, I wonder how it can be done ?

```
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.title = "Settings"
```

I tried the following as well, but it did not even show the label.

```
let navLabel = UILabel()
let navTitle = NSMutableAttributedString(string: "Settings", attributes:[
       NSAttributedString.Key.foregroundColor: UIColor.blue,
       NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 17.0, weight: UIFont.Weight.light)])

navLabel.attributedText = navTitle
self.tabBarController?.navigationItem.titleView = navTitle
```

Comment: did you try tintColor ? like `UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor( red: CGFloat(255/255.0), green: CGFloat(99/255.0), blue: CGFloat(95/255.0), alpha: CGFloat(1.0) )`

Comment: @PrashantTukadiya, it does not work.

Comment: What is your view hierarchy. can you post storyboard screenshot I am asking because you are setting `self.tabbarController.navigationItem` code I have posted is for  tabbarItem. It is unclear that you need navigation item or tabbar item

Comment: I have navigationcontroller, then viewController and then tabbarcontroller.

Comment: Try this UINavigationBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.black

Answer (score 2):

try this code, I hope it helps you.

Build Settings\Swift Language Version: 4.1

General\Deployment Target: 10.3

```
let attrsNormal = [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor : UIColor.black,
                 NSAttributedStringKey.font : UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 14)!]
    UITabBarItem.appearance().setTitleTextAttributes(attrsNormal,
                                                     for: UIControlState.normal)
```

Answer (score 0):

The size of label is right ? Call `fitThatSize`